# NestJS Dependency Injection in Websocket Adapter

Tags: websocket, dependency-injection, service, nestjs, adapter

I'm trying to authenticate and check permission of a user while establishing a websocket connection in a NestJS application.

I've found [this discussion](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/882#issuecomment-631643591) which recommends to make use of [NestJS Websocket adapter](https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/adapter). You can perform the token validation in the `options.allowRequest` callback as below.

```js
export class AuthenticatedSocketIoAdapter extends IoAdapter {

  private readonly authService: AuthService;
  constructor(private app: INestApplicationContext) {
    super(app);
    this.authService = app.get(AuthService);
  }

  createIOServer(port: number, options?: SocketIO.ServerOptions): any {
    options.allowRequest = async (request, allowFunction) => {

      const token = request.headers.authorization.replace('Bearer ', '');

      const verified = this.authService.verifyToken(token);
      if (verified) {
        return allowFunction(null, true);
      }
      
      return allowFunction('Unauthorized', false);
    };

    return super.createIOServer(port, options);
  }
}
```

I have a problem however with the dependency injection in the websocket adapter. The `IoAdapter`'s constructor has an `INestApplicationContext` parameter from which I'm trying to get back the `AuthService` using `app.get(AuthService)` as you can see above.

The AuthService injects two other services, a `UserService` and the `JwtService` to check the JWT token. My problem is that those services remained not defined in that context.

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private usersService: UsersService, private jwtService: JwtService) {}

  verifyToken(token: string): boolean {
    // Problem: this.jwtService is undefined
    const user = this.jwtService.verify(token, { publicKey });
    // ... check user has permissions and return result
  }
```

For info, the `AuthService` is in another module than the one which defines the Websocket. I also tried to import the AuthService (and its dependencies) in the current module but that didn't help.

Is that possible to make use the service using the `app.get()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve the DI issue by using `app.resolve()` instead of `app.get()`

```js
export class AuthenticatedSocketIoAdapter extends IoAdapter {
  private authService: AuthService;

  constructor(private app: INestApplicationContext) {
    super(app);
    app.resolve<AuthService>(AuthService).then((authService) => {
      this.authService = authService;
    });
  }
}
```

This solved the `jwtService` injected in the `AuthService` being undefined.